# Why does this error happen (C++)?

Tags: c++, class

I have a class called SavingsAccount with a method called calculateMonthlyInterest. If I arrange my main method like this, it works just fine, with saver1 having interest of $60 and saver2 having interest of $90:

```
void main() {

    // create two savings account objects, then calculate interest for them
    int balance = 200000;
    SavingsAccount saver1(balance);
    saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();

    balance = 300000;
    SavingsAccount saver2(balance);
    saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();
    cin.ignore(2); // keeps console from closing
}
```

However, if I arrange it like this, saver1 and saver2 both have interest of $90, even though that is incorrect for saver1:

```
void main() {

    // create two savings account objects, then calculate interest for them
    int balance = 200000;
    SavingsAccount saver1(balance);
    balance = 300000;
    SavingsAccount saver2(balance);

    saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
    saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();
    cin.ignore(2); // keeps console from closing
}
```

Obviously I can avoid the error by arranging it the first way, but I was just wondering why this is. Either way, shouldn't it pass a different value for the saver1 and saver2 objects, or am I missing something?

Edit: Here's the rest of the program for those who want to see it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class SavingsAccount {
public:
    SavingsAccount(int& initialBalance) : savingsBalance(initialBalance) {} 

    // perform interest calculation
    void calculateMonthlyInterest() { 

    /*since I am only calculating interest over one year, the time does not need to be 
    entered into the equation. However, it does need to be divided by 100 in order to 
    show the amount in dollars instead of cents. The same when showing the initial 
    balance */

        interest = (float) savingsBalance * annualInterestRate / 100; 
        cout << "The annual interest of an account with $" << (float)savingsBalance / 100 << " in it is $" << interest << endl;
    }; 

    void setAnnualInterestRate(float interestRate) {annualInterestRate = interestRate;} // interest constructor

    int getBalance() const {return savingsBalance;} // balance contructor

private:
    static float annualInterestRate;
    int& savingsBalance; 
    float interest;
};

float SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate = .03; // set interest to 3 percent
```

Comment: Can you show us your SavingAccount class definition?

Comment: My bet is `SavingsAccount` stashes the reference passed to it.

Comment: I'm guessing the balance is is stored in a static in `SavingsAccount`?

Comment: Can you show us SavingAccount class defination as well as calculateMonthlyInterest()method ?

Comment: `void main` is not legal. Use `int main`.

Comment: I think you are right, David. The assignment was to finish a program my professor had started, and in the class the initial balance is passed by reference instead of by value. Would this cause the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it this way. You have a balance. Now do you want it to be the balance to every account there is? or do you want it to have different values for different accounts?

Certainly you want it to change in different accounts. That means different accounts should have different copies of the balance. What you did in the code is declaring it as a reference and passing reference through the constructor. When you accept and assign references, it does not copy the value from one to another, rather it makes both referring to the same object (balance, in this case). Now after you have intialized both, if you change the balance in main, the change will be reflected in both accounts because the savingsBalance they have and the balance inside main are essentially the same objects.

To correct it, change the int &savingsBalance to int savingsBalance, and change SavingsAccount(int& initialBalance) to SavingsAccount(int initialBalance). That will make it accept the values stored in initialBalance.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting after David's comment. Thanks for the help!